# PHP Constants in Classes

Tags: php, oop, class, constants

I have the following code sample, which produces an error with the included constant when it is run. Could someone please show me where this is going wrong?

```
class Template {
  private $headers = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" 
  href=\"" . ROOT . "system/stylesheets/universal.css\" />";

  ... More variables and methods
}
```

Here is the error I receive. I am sure that the ROOT constant is defined, just outside of this class:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in <page.php> on line <line number>
```

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify non-static values as your members default values. And you're trying to perform dynamic (runtime) things - concatenation of the strings.

```
class Template
{
    public static headers()
    {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . ROOT . 'system/stylesheets/universal.css" />';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$headers = Template::headers()
```

Also - I missed that you're using just instance variables, not constants. In this case you can also use initialization in constructor:

```
class Template
{
    private $headers;

    public static __construct()
    {
        $this->headers = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . ROOT . 'system/stylesheets/universal.css" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @spryno724: static class method?

Comment: lol, exact duplicate solution of what i was going to recommend, i am deleting my post as you have already posted the answer.

Comment: +2 for good answer with very good example, ... well i wish i could do a +2